# Mongoid and Sidekiq, tenant propagation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, thread-safety, mongoid, sidekiq

On an application I'm building with mongodb and rails I want to build certain number of processors using sidekiq to process and transform data and save it to mongodb. To interface with mongodb I'm using mongoid. When it comes to multitenant environments, in order to not to pass "routing" information (the tenant) from each service to the persistence unit on each worker, mongoid recommends to use Thread.current to extract the information using store_in class macro ie:

```
class Band
  include Mongoid::Document
  store_in database: ->{ Thread.current[:database] }
end
```

I'm also using sharding so my collection names depends on a dynamic param too so the solution would be something like:

```
  store_in collection: ->{ Thread.current[:collection] }
```

The question I have is: How save it is to use Thread.current and store_in macro of mongoid under sidekiq workers?, should I take any consideration when using it?, Is there any other solution to this problem?

Comment: you can look into using [Celluloid](https://github.com/celluloid/celluloid) which might be better than sidekiq in this specific case... cause inside celluloid use threading to work properly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the Middleware sidekiq wiki page.

Comment: Hi Mike, many thanks for your reply, Are you recommending using middleware because a) it is not safe to use Thread.current under sidekiq workers or b) it is the transparent way to get/set global data on client-server communication on sidekiq

Comment: It's the way to set collection for ALL your workers before they are executed.  You want to do exactly this pattern: https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/blob/master/lib/sidekiq/middleware/i18n.rb